# Error: more than one library with package name 'com.reactnativecomponent.splashscreen'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, splash-screen

I'm getting following error while running app for android

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.reactnativecomponent.splashscreen'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 49.543 secs
```

my build.gradle file is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

and app/build.gradle is

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"
    import com.android.build.OutputFile

    /**
     * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
     * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
     * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
     * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
     * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
     * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
     * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
     *
     * project.ext.react = [
     *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
     *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
     *
     *   // the entry file for bundle generation
     *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
     *   bundleInDebug: false,
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
     *   bundleInRelease: true,
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
     *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
     *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
     *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
     *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
     *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
     *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
     *   // bundleInBeta: true,
     *
     *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
     *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
     *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
     *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
     *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
     *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
     *
     *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
     *   root: "../../",
     *
     *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
     *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
     *
     *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
     *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
     *
     *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
     *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
     *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
     *
     *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
     *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
     *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
     *
     *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
     *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
     *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
     *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
     *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
     *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
     *
     *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
     *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
     *
     *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
     *   extraPackagerArgs: []
     * ]
     */

    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

    /**
     * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
     *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
     *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
     * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
     * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
     * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
     */
    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

    /**
     * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
     */
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.biohotspot"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 8
            versionName "1.0"
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
        signingConfigs {
                release {
                    if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                        storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                        storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                        keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                        keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
                    }
                }
            }
        splits {
            abi {
                reset()
                enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
                include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':react-native-smart-splash-screen')
        compile project(':react-native-rw-get-gallery-image')
        compile project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')
        compile project(':react-native-background-task')
        compile project(':react-native-keep-awake')
        compile project(':react-native-background-timer')
        compile project(':react-native-image-resizer')
        compile project(':react-native-fcm')
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' //this decides your firebase SDK version
        compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
        compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
        compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        compile project(':react-native-smart-splashscreen')
        compile project(':react-native-fs')
        compile project(':react-native-file-opener')
        compile project(':react-native-camera')
    }

    // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
    // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help how can I get rid of this I will put more detail if you want.

Comment: Post your build.gradle code also

Comment: @SandeepParish I have updated the question

Comment: sorry my mistake,  post your build.gradle(module:app) complete code

Comment: @SandeepParish please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using same dependencies two times in 1st line and in 4th last line remove one from here. don't use same dependencies for multiple times

```
 dependencies {
        compile project(':react-native-smart-splash-screen')//here
        compile project(':react-native-rw-get-gallery-image')
        compile project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')
        compile project(':react-native-background-task')
        compile project(':react-native-keep-awake')
        compile project(':react-native-background-timer')
        compile project(':react-native-image-resizer')
        compile project(':react-native-fcm')
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' //this decides your firebase SDK version
        compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
        compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
        compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        compile project(':react-native-smart-splashscreen')//here
        compile project(':react-native-fs')
        compile project(':react-native-file-opener')
        compile project(':react-native-camera')
    }
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: to obtain more info about the issue, type this gradle command in the console:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies
```

The output will show you the dependencies tree for the app module. Maybe then you can clarify which dependencies are using the same package and then decide if you can exclude one of them, or at least get more info to solve the issue.